# Android %1$s is bad formatted in rtl languages

Tags: android, eclipse, string

I have this string:

> Delete "%1$s" budget?

Where %1$s is a placeholder for a string.

When I copy my translated string in ecplise it reorder the string like this:

> حذف ميزانية "%1$s"؟

Same error when I copy here the string.
How I could copy the string in ecplise in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your encoding. To do that navigate to Window--> Preferences-->General --> Workspace and change encoding to UTF-8! But keep in mind it is best practice to put all of you string in strings.xml if they do not come from database where localization happens [image]